# When I mirror bleed in my rip software, sometimes a white line will appear (File saved in Ps & Ai)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, save, white-space, white

I work at a print shop, and my RIP guy frequently runs into this problem -

I will save a file in Photoshop or Illustrator, snaping the edges to the size of the artboard, and when he opens it and adds mirrored bleed, there is a white line that shows up.

(I know a problem might be the artwork says its at the edge of the artboard, but really is a pixel or so off but this time was different)

I made a 2 by 2 grid of artboards (that were touched the edges of the next), and imported a picture that covers all 4 artboards. Theres no way there was white space on an edge of an artboard because the picture expanded past the artboards.

(INFO - Saving from Illustrator as a PDF/X-3, and using Onyx 10 to rip)

Comment: Add bleed to edges and try again.

Comment: If the photo spanned all 4 artboards. .the issue is with the RIP guy, nit the artwork. Or the fact that you aren't adding bleeds to the artboards (which you should).